# How do I pull every 10 digit code within a cell and have it pasted in a new cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in which my cells in column B contain a message (an email).  Certain messages have a 10 digit code preceded by the title ASIN:

I want to pull this 10 digit code and have it automatically pasted in a new cell.

To give an example if I have a message:
"6/2/16 sender blah@blah.com blah blah blah blah blah blah ASIN: 1A1A1A1A1A blah blah blah blah blah blah thanks"...

...I would like to have the 1A1A1A1A1A copied from the cell and pasted in a new cell.  The code can consist only letters, only numbers or a mix of both.

I'm guessing the logic would be something along the lines of:
If B:B contains "ASIN: **********" then copy and paste to C:C

Can anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself you could show us?

Comment: Use `FIND` and `MID`

Comment: from the sound of your title, it gives me the impression that you could have ASIN: more than once in the same cell.  Can you have more than 1 ten digit code in the message or is it limited to 1?  if you an have more than 1 code per message, where do you want the subsequent codes pasted?

Comment: Also, could ASIN: come up in the course of text message and not be followed by a 10 digit code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("ASIN: ",A1)+6,10)
```